# (node:38679) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead. while connecting to mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mern

(node:38679) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.

I received this warning while I was connecting to MongoDB.

this was my code

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import { DB_NAME } from "../constants.js";


const connectDB = async ( ) => {
    try {
        const connectionInstance = await mongoose.connect(`${process.env.MONGODB_URI}/${DB_NAME}`)
        console.log(`\nMongoDB connected || DB HOST: ${connectionInstance.connection.host}`)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("MongoDB connection error",error);
        process.exit(1);
    }
}


export default connectDB;
```

Comment: what version of mongoose? perhaps you need to upgrade it - a warning isn't the end of the world

Comment: @DanielA.White i am using latest  - "mongoose": "^8.0.3"

Comment: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/14104

Comment: @DanielA.White ig it will be fixed in next mongoose update thanks for help